# JavaScript snytax error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

```
<button id="KullaniciSec" type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="KullaniciSec_OnServerClick"  onclick='<%# string.Format("return SecDegerler(\"{0}\");",Eval("id")) %>' class="btn  btn-default btn-xs">
<i class="fa fa-folder-open-o fa-2x"></i>Seç  </button>
```

I will call JavaScript code from this code but I have error message and i will open console

```
 <button onclick="return SecDegerler("23"); __doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$griduser$cell0_9$TC$KullaniciSec','')" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_griduser_cell0_9_KullaniciSec_0" type="button" class="btn  btn-default btn-xs">
 <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o fa-2x"></i>Seç</button>
```

how to will be fix? And How to remove `__doPostBack`?

Comment: This question is cryptic and needs more clarification.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: My english that  Dayan . I answer this question MatthewD

Answer (score 0):

If i understood everything like you meant it:

```
 <button onclick='return SecDegerler("23");' id="ContentPlaceHolder1_griduser_cell0_9_KullaniciSec_0" type="button" class="btn  btn-default btn-xs">
```

Comment: The problem you have are the quotes. `<button onclick="return SecDegerler("23");"` You have to use outer single quotes. If there is still a syntax error it has to be somewhere else.

Comment: `onclick='<%# string.Format("return SecDegerler(\"{0}\");",Eval("id")) %>' ` is server side code that will output the return statement to be used inside the client side `onclick`. But the problem is that he is escaping the `"` on the server but should be using `&quot;` for double quotes. So technically it should look like so: `onclick='<%# string.Format("return SecDegerler(&quot;{0}&quot;);",Eval("id")) %>'`